# How to push an existing branch in a new gitlab repository?

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab, I have two repositories A and B. I want to clone a branch from repository A and push it to repository B with a different branch name.
what's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clone your repoA and checkout say "branch-a" in repo A

```
git clone <repo-A git url>

cd repo-A

git checkout branch-a
```

Add repo B as a new origin(origin2)

```
git remote add origin2 <repo B git url>
```

Push the branch-a to repo-B with new name(say branch-b)

```
git push origin2 branch-a:branch-b
```

After this you should see `branch-b` in repo-B